# 2D array cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, arrays, graph, int

I am working on another homework assignment, and I'm stuck with this problem. My 2D int[][] graph1 (array) "cannot be resolved to a variable"?

Basically, I translated some graphs to 2D arrays, that must be uploaded into a program that will read if they are a PATH, or CIRCUIT. One is a directed graph, the other (which I'm on now) is undirected.

This is what I have so far:

```
boolean undirectedCircuit (int [][] graph)
{
    //graph = graph1(graph1(null));

    int edgeCounter = 0;

    for (int edge = 0; edge < graph.length; edge++)
    {
        /* SET FOR WHEN 1s are found in array: edgeCounter++;*/
        if(graph[4][4] == '1')
        {
            edgeCounter++;
            System.out.println("edgeCounter found '1' " + edgeCounter + "times");
        }
    }

    if (edgeCounter % 2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a circuit!");
        //return true;
    }
    else System.out.println("This is not a circuit!!");
    return false;
    }

public void go ()
{
    graph1 = new int[][] //This line is complained about.
            {
            {0,1,1,1,0},
            {1,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,1,0},
            {1,0,1,0,1},
            {0,1,0,1,0}
            };

    undirectedCircuit(graph1); //This is complained about.
}
```

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Where is `graph1` being declared?

Comment: You should change `graph1 = new int[][] ...` to `int[][] graph1 = new int[][] ...` if it's not declared elsewhere

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja, I literally thought of that hours ago, but didn't think of implementing it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @HowbeitGirl I made my comment into an answer; please accept it if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never declared `graph1`.

You should change `graph1 = new int[][] ...` to `int[][] graph1 = new int[][] ...`

Answer (score 1):

> graph1 (array) "cannot be resolved to a variable

You haven't declared `graph1`, so compiler cannot resolve symbol `graph1`.

Solution:-

```
graph1 = new int[][] //This line is complained about.
            {
            {0,1,1,1,0},
            {1,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,1,0},
            {1,0,1,0,1},
            {0,1,0,1,0}
            };
```

should be

```
int[][] graph1 = 
            {
            {0,1,1,1,0},
            {1,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,1,0},
            {1,0,1,0,1},
            {0,1,0,1,0}
            };
```